# Python Package script works only on Linux

Tags: python, linux, windows, setuptools, setup.py

I am having a weird problem with my PyPi package. It seems that the `pydownloader` script works only on Linux/MacOS systems. The package is `pythondl`, so when you install it you can run `pydownloader` in the terminal, but that does not seem to work in windows. How can i set it up so the script will work in windows?

## Info:

Tree:

```
.
├── build
│   ├── bdist.linux-x86_64
│   ├── lib
│   │   └── pythondl
│   │       └── __init__.py
│   ├── pydownloader
│   │   ├── Analysis-00.toc
│   │   ├── base_library.zip
│   │   ├── COLLECT-00.toc
│   │   ├── EXE-00.toc
│   │   ├── localpycos
│   │   │   └── struct.pyo
│   │   ├── PKG-00.pkg
│   │   ├── PKG-00.toc
│   │   ├── pydownloader
│   │   ├── PYZ-00.pyz
│   │   ├── PYZ-00.toc
│   │   ├── Tree-00.toc
│   │   ├── Tree-01.toc
│   │   ├── warn-pydownloader.txt
│   │   └── xref-pydownloader.html
│   └── scripts-3.8
│       └── pydownloader
├── dist
│   ├── pythondl-1.1.1-py3-none-any.whl
│   └── pythondl-1.1.1.tar.gz
├── install.sh
├── LICENSE
├── MANIFEST.in
├── pydownloader.spec
├── pythondl
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── __pycache__
│       └── __init__.cpython-38.pyc
├── pythondl.egg-info
│   ├── dependency_links.txt
│   ├── PKG-INFO
│   ├── requires.txt
│   ├── SOURCES.txt
│   └── top_level.txt
├── README.md
├── requirements.txt
├── scripts
│   └── pydownloader
└── setup.py
```

Setup.py:

```py
import pathlib
from setuptools import setup

# Get README:
HERE = pathlib.Path(__file__).parent
README = (HERE / "README.md").read_text()

# Setup:
setup(
    name='pythondl',
    version='1.1.1',
    description='Download YT videos using this simple tool!',
    long_description=README,
    long_description_content_type="text/markdown",
    author='Calamity34',
    author_email='nick.goloushckin@ya.ru',
    license="MIT",
    classifiers=[
        "License :: OSI Approved :: MIT License",
        "Programming Language :: Python :: 3",
        "Programming Language :: Python :: 3.8"
    ],
    packages=['pythondl'],
    install_requires=['bs4','beautifulsoup4','pytube3','requests'],
    scripts = [
        'scripts/pydownloader'
    ]
)
```

Comment: Can you use [`youtube_dl`](https://pypi.org/project/youtube_dl/#history) instead?

Comment: its weird, pytube is more familiar to me tho